# Python - split string and return int

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, split, int

```
x='2013:02:01'

y,m,d=x.split(':')
```

Produces y,m,d as strings.  But how do I produce them as ints using only 1 line

Failed:

```
y,m,d=int(y.split(':'))


y,m,d=int(y),int(m),int(d)=y.split(':')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
y, m, d = map(int, x.split(':'))
```

`map` applies the function to each of the elements in the iterable. In this case it will apply `int` to each of the values returned by `split` and give you the result.

Comment: beat me by 3 seconds ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[ int(token) for token in y.split(':') ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use list comprehensions:

```
y,m,d = [int(n) for n in x.split(':')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehension will do the trick:

```
>>> x='2013:02:01'
>>> y,m,d=[int(n) for n in x.split(':')]
>>> y
2013
>>> d
1
>>> m
2
```